# What is the source of this error? ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.add-iam-policy-binding) NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-iam

I'm working through the example at [this URL](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler), but I'm running into the error below. **What is the source of that error?**

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.add-iam-policy-binding) NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found.
```

I'm running the script below, but obviously with a different parameter set. I verified in the GUI/Console that the service account was created, the `$serviceAccount` variable has the correct value, the service exists, and the service name is correct. Also, I'm able to manually add the service account to the service in the invoker role in the GUI/Console.

```
param(
    $cloudRunInvokerServiceAccount = 'some-service-account',
    $projectId = 'some-project-id',
    $nameOfServiceBeingInvoked = 'some-service'                                
)

gcloud iam service-accounts create $cloudRunInvokerServiceAccount --display-name $cloudRunInvokerServiceAccount

$serviceAccount = "serviceAccount:$cloudRunInvokerServiceAccount@$projectId.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding $nameOfServiceBeingInvoked `
   --member=$serviceAccount `
   --role=roles/run.invoker `
   --platform=managed
```

I also reviewed [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/services/add-iam-policy-binding) for good measure.

Also, I ran `gcloud run services list` and `gcloud iam service-accounts list` to verify the existence of the services/accounts and their status (enabled).

Comment: I think you have a CLI version incompatibility issue. Are you running an old version of the CLI `gcloud`? The current version is `320.0.0` (`gcloud version)` To update run `gcloud components update` in an elevated prompt (Windows) or with sudo (LInux).

Comment: @JohnHanley, you're correct. If you answer, I'll accept.

Comment: What version were you running for my notes?

Comment: @JohnHanley, sorry, I'm not sure. It was fairly old though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this error with old versions of the Google Cloud CLI `gcloud`.

The solution is to update the Google Cloud SDK and components.

Windows:

- Open an elevated Windows Commmand Prompt.
- Execute this command and follow the prompts: `gcloud components update`

Linux:

- Execute this command and follow the prompts: `sudo gcloud components update`